# react-native run-android Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file

Tags: android, react-native

I try to

```
react-native run-android
```

and meet 
this problem

```
JS server already running.
Running C:\Users\丶丶困困兽兽犹犹斗斗\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 192.168.76.101:5555 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug...
Unzipping C:\Users\丶丶困困兽兽犹犹斗斗\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.4-all\6r4uqcc6ovnq6ac6s0txzcpc0\gradle-2.4-all.zip to C:\Users\丶丶困困兽兽犹犹斗斗\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.4-all\6r4uqcc6ovnq6ac6s0txzcpc0Exception in thread "main"    java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:114)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:131)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:159)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$500(Install.java:26)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:69)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:46)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:46)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:126)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
```

SDK works well and can find device in adb devices

Comment: Hi Wenpeng. Have you solved this yet?

Comment: not yettttttttt

Answer (score 19):

The problem is Unable to Unzip your gradle-2.4-all.zip, 
So please Delete the existing file

> gradle-2.4-all.zip

from your folder :

> C:\Users\丶丶困困兽兽犹犹斗斗.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.4-all\6r4uqcc6ovnq6ac6s0txzcpc0\

Download a fresh gradle-2.4-all.zip file and place it on the same folder as we deleted and try again to run your code : react-native run-android

It may work.You can download gradle zip file from the below Link: https://services.gradle.org/distributions

Answer (score 12):

I have the same problem as yours!
Because when I first run "react-native run-android", my **INTERNET** is **SLOW** and **LAG**, **CORRUPTED**. This bad internet connection lets to download a TEMPORARY DAMAGE file gradle....zip. 
**Solution**: Just **go in that path contains** that file zip, **delete** it then **run again**! It worked for me!

Answer (score 6):

Well, I meet the same problem.

I use this method solve it.

I input: `sudo react-native run-android`

then the Terminal show :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: SDK location not found. Define location
>   with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME
>   environment variable.

So I copy a "`local.properties`" from an existing Android project and put it in this project.

And then,I input `sudo react-native run-android` again.

Comment: That error message is completely different. You would see this `RuntimeException` **before** the `ZipException`, I believe

Comment: Also, the question is on a Windows machine, so that `sudo` usage doesn't do any good

Comment: Yeah，you are right.i did not notice his michine. I solve it in mac.I google for

Comment: I google for this problem long time and get nothing.So hope this can be help

Answer (score 4):

Content in file gradle-2.4-all error.
Please delete content in gradle-2.4-all (~/.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.4-all...) then re-compile .. it will auto download file.

Answer (score 2):

I just experienced the same problem as yours. When I run `react-native run-android`, I got the error message:

`Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file`

I use Mac and apparently the problem was caused by the react-native CLI that is failed to write the Gradle zip file to certain folder due to lack of permission. In my case, I tried to ran the command again this time using sudo: `sudo react-native run-android`, and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

The `gradle-2.4-all.zip` was damaged,so it should be replaced with a new `gradle-2.4-all.zip`

Answer (score 1):

One of the causes of this problem (since late 2019) is the [decommissioning of HTTP services by Gradle](https://blog.gradle.org/decommissioning-http). This means that if your `[PROJECT_PATH]/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file has an entry like:

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-{version}.zip
```

... then this entry will try to retrieve a `ZIP` file from a service no longer servicing it (`http` based one) and it will silently return an empty `ZIP` file; which consequentially will be the source of an error from any process trying to unzip that empty `ZIP` file.

To fix this, just change your `[PROJECT_PATH]/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file to have its `distributionUrl` entry to use `https`:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-{version}.zip
```

Hope this helps.

update the line in ../android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip`

Answer (score 0):

I think you could download the gradle-2.4-all.zip from [here](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/),unzip it to your `.gradle`.

Comment: What OP needs is VPN.

Answer (score 0):

For me I just deleted `.gradle` folder and then tried again. It re-downloaded libraries and it worked.

P.S.

I think in new configuration there is no `.zip` file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the same as you.

Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file.

just use *sudo react-native run-android* insted of *react-native run-android*