# How properly run a react-native project on win10?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, windows, react-native

I created project with react-native-cli on Win10:
`react-native init ShoppingList`
But when I run `react-native run-android --no-jetifier`
I get error. I wrote **ANDROID_HOME**, **JAVA_HOME**, **...Sdk\platform-tools** in system environment. I rewrote gradle wrapper versions from 6.2 to 6.3
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ciao, you already tried [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56891033/facing-issue-failed-to-install-the-app-make-sure-you-have-the-android-develop) right?

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by an incompatibility between JDK14 and gradle wrapper versions less than 6.3.
Go to `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` and update the gradle to 6.3

`distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip`

Comment: I rewrote gradle wrapper versions from 6.2 to 6.3
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip
And got: Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.

Comment: Mayby I need install Android 10.0 (Q) API Level 29 instead Android 10.0 +(R) API Level 30 ?

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled Android 10.0 (Q) API Level 29 instead of Android 10.0 +(R) API Level 30 and this resolved my problem. Maybe it was a conflict with gradle version.
Thanks to all.

Comment: it had to be either one of them, gradle or android API level, cheers