# react native android emulator error: Failed to install the app

Tags: android, react-native

[error capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0KqQ.png)

How can I fix this error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56891033/facing-issue-failed-to-install-the-app-make-sure-you-have-the-android-develop

Answer (score 0):

Please read your error log. It said that the Android SDK location does not found. Please do the following instruction from react native official documents.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup