# Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 (Tried all answers in other similar questions.)

Tags: android, react-native, debugging

I have a problem while working on React-Native project. It is working for iOS. I've tried all the answers regarding this error but none of them is working.

Error Log :

Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app'.
- Try:
  Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

I'll provide you with the necessary information needed.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `Java` path is not set properly. Try adding this to your `android/gradle.properties`.

```
# Your java path here
org.gradle.java.home=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_91
```

If this doesn't help try one of the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56891033/facing-issue-failed-to-install-the-app-make-sure-you-have-the-android-develop).

Comment: I've set the Java path to correct folder still not working!. I ran sudo ./gradlew assembleDebug in my android folder and is working. Still facing the same issue! I'm on a Mac Device.

Comment: @ChetanjeevSinghBains Please run `npx react-native doctor` it will give you the detail about development environment and missing dependencies