# npx react-native run-android build failing

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-studio

I have just created a react-native project and followed all the docs. when I am trying to run  npx react-native run-android I am getting the following error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtqSt.jpg)

resolved the above error. now the error is coming like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5Sgy.jpg)

Comment: It is always great if you post error as text instead of image

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Facing issue " Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment " in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56891033/facing-issue-failed-to-install-the-app-make-sure-you-have-the-android-develop)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by deleting .gradle directory in app/android folder.